# Show Past Cases on the Case Page Layout?

Tags: visualforce, case, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I'd like to show "Past Logged Cases" on the Case Console for Service Cloud.  This would be Cases logged by the Case.Contact.

Anyone have a simple idea how to do this, or are we talking VF/Lightning?

From a Contact Page, it's easy...but I want to be looking at the Case and see what the Contact has logged prior.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With `Visualforce`, you can use the `apex:relatedList` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm).

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:relatedList subject="Case.ContactId" list="Cases" />
</apex:page>
```

Note that this approach will just show all siblings. If you want a filtered list you will need to build out a more custom implementation using `Apex`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'related case' on the Contact custom console component. 
I've explained how in the following question: [visualforce page to list cases by contact using 'case.AccountId' for Person Account - Lightning Design](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132608/visualforce-page-to-list-cases-by-contact-using-case-accountid-for-person-acco/132800?noredirect=1#comment191765_132800)

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant information here? Links tend to break over time meaning link-only answers aren't that useful. Chances are the reason you've been downvoted is that people believe this to simply be promotion for your blog... if that is the case you can see that it's not tolerated well by the community.