# visualforce page to list cases by contact using 'case.AccountId' for Person Account - Lightning Design

Tags: apex, visualforce, service-cloud-console, list-view, lightning-design-system

I have a business use case demand to show a list of Cases for the current associated Contact on the Case Feed in Service Console.

I was able to achieve this with the below VisualForce Page:

[image]

I was able to generate the list view but it renders in Classic view.

I am trying to generate Lightning view with the below code but I am getting this error and have no idea how to resolve it. I am sys admin and have no coding experience. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Could anyone help me with the code to achieve this list view in lightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing the '/' as a closing tag for apex:stylesheet. 
Can you place the below line instead and retry:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS080, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css')}" />
```

As a side note, here's a code I written, which renders the related cases in Lightning view:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="true">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried and I am getting different errors now. I am posting the error message I am getting after changing the code as per your suggestion. Could you post a pic of your code and do I have create any VF component to achieve this result? Error Message: **Error: Static Resource named SLDS080 does not exist. Check spelling.**

Comment: Hi SandyAdmin. I believe this new error implies the lack of Lightning Design System in your SalesForce environment. Please follow the instructions in this Trail to add this as a Static Resource: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-1

Comment: Please also note the similar question I had and follow the answer to resolve your matter: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126752/visualforce-page-to-list-cases-by-contact-using-case-contactid-lightning-des

Comment: Hi @iDog, I tried adding the static resource as SLDS080 by downloading it from the link you have provided. This is the code I am using.  '<apex:page standardController="Case" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{$Resource.SLDS080,'/resource/SLDS080/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css'}"/>
<apex:relatedList list="Cases" subject="{!Case.AccountID}"/>
</apex:page>' . I followed your question and tried the same but I am getting a different result. Could you post your code so that I can try it out to get the same result or not.

Comment: Absolutely. Here is my code:   <apex:page standardcontroller="Case" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="true">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS080, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css')}" />
<div class="slds-text-body--small">
<div class="slds-scrollable">
        <apex:relatedList list="Cases" subject="{!Case.ContactId}"/>
</div>
</div>
</apex:page>

Comment: Thank you buddy, I was finally able to get the desired outlook. The difference is in referencing the SLDS resource. I was referencing it at "{$Resource.SLDS080,'/resource/SLDS080/assets/" where as in your code it is referenced as "{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS080, 'assets/". Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @iDog, I am facing a small problem with the list, I can see related cases for the contact and when I click on any of the case number or other fields, it does nothing. But if I click on New Case it is opening a new case page. Did you check your list view if it is pulling the case info or not? Any idea why it is not opening the case info?

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get the lightning design.  Regards the functionality of the list, I can confirm this is not working for me either. I suppose this can be achieved, but for me, the out-of-the-box related cases in the Contact and Account records was a better solution (see here - http://www.screencast.com/t/l9ZhklHG).

Comment: Hi @iDog how can we achieve the out of the box functionality? Can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm seeing you have a custom object (enquiries), which is a little different then what I made - Cased by Contact, but this should be quite the same. On the Setup page -> Customize -> Contact -> select  Edit on the active Page Layout ->  Mini Page Layout -> under Related Lists - tick 'Cases' along with the desired columns.  After completing this, add the 'Contact' as a Custom Console Component on your entity Page Layout.   Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @iDog Enquiries are cases. They have renamed cases to enquiries for their convenience. I will try out your suggestion and see if it works out or not.

Comment: The out of the box functionality worked out. It was easy to show the related cases with OOB rather than the code and worst part the links don't work in the code. Thank you for all the help buddy.

Comment: Hi @iDog Sorry to bother you. I was able to achieve the functionality in one of the Dev Sandbox and when I am trying the same in UAT Sandbox, it doesn't display any cases related to the contact. I am attaching a screenshot to show what I am able to see in both orgs. The one with blue letters is Dev org and Red is UAT. I have done everything in the same way but don't  understand why it isn't working. Could you help me where I am going wrong or any idea why it isn't pulling any cases for the same contact. This is the link to see the image. http://www.screencast.com/t/cS5E5myxyd

Comment: Hi @iDog Sorry to bother you. Ignore the previous message, I found the problem but not the solution. I was able to achieve the functionality only if I have created the contact manually. For contacts which exist in the system, it doesn't pull the cases which is weird. I am not sure why it is not displaying cases related to the same contact which were existing in the system. Any idea how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi @iDog, Found the main problem why it isn't displaying for others, it shows related cases only for business accounts and not to person accounts.