# Create Button in Communities to redirect to external URL

Tags: custom-button, community, url, redirect

I have a use case where I have to provide a button in the community page, it can be displayed in the community home page or in a detail page. The button has to open a new tab or page with the url it is embedded with. I checked the Global actions to add a new action to redirect to a page but the global actions doesn't have that facility.

Is there any way I can create a button that redirects to external page in Communities. I am using Napili template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the component from lightning exchange for this requirement .This will avoid you coding lightning component for same .

Here is the appexchange app for your requirement .This app is free.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EA6PTUA1

Comment: Thanks Mohith. Installing the app from app exchange saved a lot of time. Could you help me with the lightning view render for related cases list view please.

Comment: Hi Mohith, I posted it as a separate question. Here is the link [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132608/visualforce-page-to-list-cases-by-contact-using-case-accountid-for-person-acco]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a button with a lightning component for redirection and add it to the community home page.
Or I think you could even do it with the richtextarea in the Napili.

Comment: Hi, I searched for couple of forums to create a lightning component for a button but they were discreet in creating the button and I am a sys admin and can't code, that's why I was looking for a solution which I will be able to do it by myself with some guidance. Thank you for your reply.